# MagnificPopup without button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, magnific-popup

I am using MagnificPopup to display a popup after loading something using jQuery's `get()` method. When the `get()` call completes, I want to display the popup below:

```
<div id="tagsearch-popup" class="panel panel-default mfp-hide">
    <div class="panel-heading">Tag Search</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
            Example
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery that I am using.

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
   success: {
      $("#recalculation-guid").html(data);
      // Display popup now
   }
});
```

However, when I look through the MagnificPopup examples I can only find examples for binding the popup to a button. I want to create it programatically.

How can I use MagnificPopup to convert the `<div>`s above into a popup without a button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a method called open:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: 'someimage.jpg'
  },
  type: 'image'

  // You may add options here, they're exactly the same as for $.fn.magnificPopup call
  // Note that some settings that rely on click event (like disableOn or midClick) will not work here
}, 0);
 //and also close, if you're into that ;)
$.magnificPopup.close();
```

So in your code:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
   success: {
   $("#recalculation-guid").html(data);
   // Display popup now
   $.magnificPopup.open({...});
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    alert("clicked");
    // your instantiation
});
$("a").click();
```

What you need to do is to trigger the click that you instantiate your `MagnificPopup`.